# How to increase font size and use bolds?

Tags: support

How to increase font size and use bolds? And other formatting?

Comment: Does this help? https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @Sklivvz it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bold**

```
 **Bold**
```

### Header 2

```
 Header 2
 ---
```

## Header 1

```
 Header 1
 ===
```

Paragraph

```
 Paragraph
```

This syntax style is called Markdown. [These functions and more are documented here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and many are available for quick use with the bar above the text field.

[image: answer text field with edit bar]